# How to show installer to the user

Tags: c#, windows, installation, windows-installer

When the user clicks update on my application, I want to show the installer.
The installer resides on a server.

What is the best way to show msi or installer to the user?

Is there any example?

Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, have you had a look at using ClickOnce (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to copy your installation package to the client. You can transfer binary data or download using `WebClient`.

Then you can execute the installation package using `Process.Start` and `msiexec` utility

```
msiexec /quiet /i "c:\myinstallationpackage.msi" // for hidden installation
msiexec /qb /i "c:\myinstallationpackage.msi" // for installation with base steps without any actions from the user
msiexec /i "c:\myinstallationpackage.msi" // usual installation
```

Answer (score 0):

After you download the msi file, you just run it using the Process class found in System.Diagnostics namespace.

Windows will take care after that.

LATER EDIT:
Sample code:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\install.msi", string.Empty);
```

Of course the path to your downloaded .msi file should point to a temporary directory (a good choice would be the Windows temporary folder itself), but the idea is to get to call the static method Start() of the Process class.