# Uninstallation of Application Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, installation

I have used the following code for uninstalling my c# application through programmatically.

```
string[] arguments = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
foreach (string argument in arguments)
{
   if (argument.Split('=')[0].ToLower() == "/u")
   {
        string guid = argument.Split('=')[1];
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System);
        ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "/msiexec.exe", "/x " + guid);
        Process.Start(si);
        Application.Exit();
   }
}
```

the code above i works fine and uninstalls my S/w correctly.

But my requirement is that how can i get the "Yes" button click event of that unistallation confirmation box.

Comment: I don't understand. Please elaborate? Also, why don't you let the install tool that you use do this for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with params and use `quiet` or `base` modes to not interact with user at all. I've described this approach in answer here: [How to show installer to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338923/how-to-show-installer-to-the-user/7338973#7338973)

In case of using "base" mode (`msiexec /qb`) user will see only progress bar without any questions.

Comment: similerly i dont want user interaction in uninstalltion of software

Comment: so, use "quiet" to not show anything to user, or "basic" too show only uninstallation progress.

Comment: Check the link I posted in the answer. It's need just to provide params to 'msiexec` utility. Also in the answer I've already provided params for basic progress mode.

Comment: But you posted the code for installation & i want to "Uninstall" the application than what changes required in following line ProcessStartInfo si = new ProcessStartInfo(path + "/msiexec.exe", "/x " + guid);

Comment: So? just add to your start info one more param: `"/qb /x " + guid`. Here is the list of all options and samples of utility options format if you will need some other http://ss64.com/nt/msiexec.html